# Disbale autocompletion for s:password and s:textfield in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, migration, textfield, struts-1

Currently we are migrating our Struts1 application to Struts2. While changing JSP tags to Struts2, we have in Struts1 for `html:text` there is attribute

```
autocomplete=\"off"
```

Which disable auto fill for text box.
But when I am trying to add same for `s:textfield` and `s:password` it is giving me warning like **"Undefined attribute name 'autocomplete'"**
Which attribute I need to use in Struts2?

Answer (score 1):

> warning like **"Undefined attribute name 'autocomplete'"**

It's just warning, which means a dynamic attribute. You can turn off a developer mode to disable it.